# Hyperlinks not working in PrinceXML

Tags: php, pdf, hyperlink, princexml

If I write below code in html file to convert it to PDF with prince factory it is not working properly.

```
<a href="http://example.com">http://google.com</a>
```

This above link in pdf generated from prince xml is working properly, but it is pointing to google.com instead of example.com

```
<a href="http://example.com">Google</a>
```

This link will not work as we have not written anything before google as http or https.

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use <a href="http://example.com"> instead of <a href="http://example.com> . You forgot to close the tag.

Comment: Apologies! but it is written like this only.. and still not working

Comment: Some PDF viewers convert strings (with or without a-tags around) to clickable links. Perhaps, this describes your first behaviour.

Comment: @KevinHorst any idea what I have to do now to make it working??

Comment: Which version of PrinceXML to you use and can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for this. But the problem was not with PrinceXML. later after so much investigation, I found that it was problem with merging 2 documents in FPDF.

I used Zend Merger for merging 2 documents which were created by PrinceXML and it worked perfect.

Apologies and Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with css model

Html

```
<a href="http://example.com"><span class="linkContent"></a>
```

CSS

```
.linkContent {
    content: "http://google.com"
}
```

Refer doc: https://www.princexml.com/doc/8.1/gen-content/

Hope it can help you!

Comment: This is not working.. it is again generating hyperlink with added content as google.com

Answer (score 1):

hi you have to check the "prince-pdf-link-type" property.
by default value is auto, try to change to "web" : 
https://www.princexml.com/doc/properties/prince-pdf-link-type/

Comment: How can I use this? With style tag? If possible can you please give me any example for the same.. Thanks again!

Comment: can you show your code? to see what are you missed 
what language you use ? PHP ?